# Pandas read_excel method skipping rows

Tags: excel, pandas

I'm reading a xls file using the read_excel method from pandas. This is the Excel file:

[image: Excel file]

As you can see, the A2 and B2 cells are merged into one. Because of that, the dataframe object returned from the read_excel method is starting from line 3. When I print the names of the first two columns of the dataframe object, it prints the A3 and B3 cells.

As a result, I don't have access to the two first rows, but I need them. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'path',header=None)
```

you should receive from one merged cell eg. `RECEITA TOTAL` two cells: `RECEITA TOTAL` and `NaN`.